# How to get R's loess and R's lowess functions to give same result?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

how can this result of loess fit using `loess` be reproduced with `lowess`?

*loess code*:

```
> data = data.frame(x=c(1,0.5,3,4,5,5.5,6,7), y=c(10, 25, 38, 44.5, 500, 550, 600, 705))
> fit = loess("y ~ x", data=data)
> new_y = predict(fit, data$x)
> new_y
[1]   6.251022  28.272100  -2.840750 150.006042 481.927307 563.161187 640.825415 693.166150
```

*lowess code*:

```
> new_fit = lowess(data, f=0.8)
> new_fit
$x
[1] 0.5 1.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 5.5 6.0 7.0

$y
[1]  -4.330119  38.931265 255.000000 400.000000 500.000000 550.241949 601.519903 704.247275
```

The results are very different. I am trying to get new fitted values for `y` given values of `x`. `loess` gives

```
[1]   6.251022  28.272100  -2.840750 150.006042 481.927307 563.161187 640.825415 693.166150
```

While `lowess` gives:

```
[1]  -4.330119  38.931265 255.000000 400.000000 500.000000 550.241949 601.519903 704.247275
```

How can I rewrite my `lowess` call to give very similar results for new `y` values as `predict` with `loess` fit and `x` values? thanks.

Comment: The same? Unreasonable request? I'm not the close-voter but I do understand the impulse.

Comment: @Dwin: obviously, when I say same, I mean similar.  -2.8 and 255 are not similar.

Comment: I do think it unreasonable to expect two different nonparametric smoothers to produce "the same result" at all points from a tiny dataset that has greater then two log10's of range. They pick a different "shift point" and picking shift points is notoriously difficult.

Comment: There are some information here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2003-September/002337.html

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need this?

I don't think it can be done in the general case. Here is a specific case, which gives almost identical results, but the last value is still different for some reason:

```
fit1 <- loess(y~x,data=data,span=0.8,degree=1)
predict(fit1)
#[1]  19.08622  12.55692  37.93642 188.35019 401.53528 506.87040 591.41854 740.71060

fit2 <- lowess(data$x,data$y,f=0.8,iter=0)
fit2

# $x
# [1] 0.5 1.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 5.5 6.0 7.0
# 
# $y
# [1]  12.55692  19.08622  37.93642 188.35019 401.53528 506.87040 591.41854 741.12187
#Note that lowess reorders by x.
```

Comment: But how can you make it similar to the default features of `loess`? I want to do this since `lowess` is faster and I'm not using the equation features of `loess`, just a simple `y~x`

Comment: Maybe instead of demanding equality you should explain what "features" of `loess` that you prefer.

Comment: @DWin: `loess` worked on my data. So I just want that functionality but faster. It's not unreasonable to assume they should give similar answers... it's confusing that the defaults are wildly different

Comment: The last value is identical if you add `surface = "direct"` to the loess call. Anyway, the curves look different in this case because the default degree in loess is 2, while lowess only implements degree 1.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the reason it cannot be done is that the two functions use distinct algorithms under the hood, and the only explanation of that I could find is by Brian Ripley on here:

http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg63623.html

```
"It is not possible: the algorithms differ considerably in their details. 

...

In determining 'local' loess() uses a tricubic weighting, lowess() uses a 
uniform weighting (on reading the code)."
```

The documentation makes it clear how to choose the `span`/`f` parameters to be similar to the default, but all other parameters are not inter-translatable between the two functions because of the distinct smoothing algorithms used.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = data.frame(x=c(1,0.5,3,4,5,5.5,6,7), y=c(10, 25, 38, 44.5, 500, 550, 600, 705))
 fit = loess("y ~ x", data=data)
 new_y = predict(fit, data$x)
 plot( data$x , new_y)
lines(lowess(data, f=0.8)$x, lowess(data, f=0.8)$y)
# Obviously lowess with f=0.8 is giving different smoothing
```

Compare to a lower f-value

```
lines(lowess(data, f=0.8)$x, lowess(data, f=0.5)$y, col="red")
```

[image]